# Cross-correlation and auto-correlation of an image using $\tt fft$

Tags: matlab, image-processing, ifft

I'm working on a project where I have to find the auto-correlation and cross- correlation of types of pixels in an image:

[image]

I am using MATLAB and my code for the autocorrelation is:

```
fftimage = fft2(image);
congfft = conj(fftimage);%conjugate
ans1 = fftimage*congfft;
ans2 = ifft2(ans1);
ans3 = abs(ans2);
ans3 = fftshift(ans3);
image(ans3,'CDataMapping','scaled')
```

for the cross-correlation

```
 ans1 = fftimage*congfft2; %congfft2: conjugate the other type of pixel.
```

I don't understand clearly the outputs of the code. Here is the autocorrelation output of the yellow pixels:

[image: autocorr yellow pixels]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 1D signals, the autocorrelation of a rectangular pulse will be a triangular pulse.

For your image, the autocorrelation will be a triangular pulse in both directions.

The image below shows:

- The original image
- The autocorrelation without zero padding
- The autocorrelation **with** zero padding
- The autocorrelation **with** zero padding, viewed as a mesh.

For your example image, the zero padding is not required because the support of the non-zero pixels is way less than the image size. For non-zero pixels covering the whole image, you'll need to zero pad when using the FFT.

Your image does not appear to show the gradual change. I suspect you will need to normalize the pixel values manually. It's not clear to me that `'CDataMapping','scaled'` does the right thing (it may, I'm just not familiar with it).

[image: Triangular pulse]

---

> what does the output value in each pixel mean for the auto and the cross-correlation?

As calculated, not much.  It would mean a little more if the mean was subtracted from the image before calculation. As it is, the  most you are seeing is the auto-correlation of the mean pixel value (128?) over a limited range.

If the mean were subtracted, then it would tell you about how each pixel influences the pixels around it: if the autocorrelation values are close to zero, then that means "not much". If the autocorrelation values are high, then it means "greatly".

---

**R Code Below**

```
# 32079

par(mfrow=c(2,2))
image <- array(0,c(20,20))
image[8:13,8:13] <- 1
image(image, col= grey(seq(0, 1, length = 256)))
title("Original")

fftimage <- fft(image)
congfft <- Conj(fftimage)
ans1 <- fftimage * congfft
ans2 <- Re(fft(ans1, inverse=TRUE))/20/20
image(ans2, col= grey(seq(0, 1, length = 256)))
title("Without zero padding")

imagePadded <- array(0,c(40,40))
imagePadded[11:30,11:30] <- image
fftimagePadded <- fft(imagePadded)
congfftPadded <- Conj(fftimagePadded)
ans1a <- fftimagePadded * congfftPadded
ans2a <- Re(fft(ans1a, inverse=TRUE))/40/40
image(ans2a/max(ans2a), col= grey(seq(0, 1, length = 256)))
title("WITH zero padding")


persp(ans2a, theta=30)
title('Mesh plot WITH zero padding')
```

Comment: Many thanks! I would like to know what does the output value in each pixel mean for the auto and the cross-correlation. I am new to these transformations in 2D

Comment: @Rprolix : You're welcome! I've added an attempt to answer your question.